# Spark DataFrame duplicate column names while using mergeSchema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a huge Spark DataFrame which I create using the following statement

```
val df = sqlContext.read.option("mergeSchema", "true").parquet("parquet/partitions/path")
```

Now when I try to do column rename or select operation on above DataFrame it fails saying ambiguous columns found with the following exception

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'Product_Type' is
>   ambiguous, could be Product_Type#13, Product_Type#235

Now I saw columns and found there are two columns `Product_Type` and `Product_type` which seems to be same columns with one letter case different created because of schema merge over time. Now I don't mind keeping duplicate columns but Spark sqlContext for some reason don't like it.

I believe by default `spark.sql.caseSensitive` config is true so don't know why it fails. I am using Spark 1.5.2. I am new to Spark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `spark.sql.caseSensitive` property is `false` so before your `rename` or `select` statement, you should set the property to `true`

```
sqlContext.sql("set spark.sql.caseSensitive=true")
```

Comment: This will solve this issue but create another issue. When you select your columns your application should be already considering the case sensitivity. And if you call `transformTo` spark seems to search for lowercase columns only